# How to encode a json object into a URL search parameter using the smallest number of characters?

Tags: json, typescript, url, compression

#### Problem

I have a web app where users can play around with the settings and create/modify generative artworks and then be able to share their creation via a link [example](https://generativestudios.app/stained-glass?version=1&artwork=eyJzZWVkIjoiMjg5NjI1NDIiLCJzcGxpdHRpbmdTdHJhdGVneSI6IlNwbGl0IFJhbmRvbSBCYWxhbmNlZCIsImRlcHRoU3RyYXRlZ3kiOnsia2luZCI6IkluaGVyaXRlZCBEZXB0aCIsImRlcHRoIjo0fSwiZGlzdFN0cmF0ZWd5Ijp7ImtpbmQiOiJYIENlbnRyb2lkIn0sImppdHRlciI6MCwicGFsZXR0ZSI6eyJyZWQiOnsiYSI6MC40LCJiIjowLjU3OTAyMTk5Nzg4MjMxMTUsImMiOjAuNCwiZCI6MH0sImdyZWVuIjp7ImEiOjAuMiwiYiI6MC42MTE4ODc4NDg2MTc1MDUyLCJjIjowLjgsImQiOjB9LCJibHVlIjp7ImEiOjAuNiwiYiI6MC45MzA0MzA2NDU0OTUzOTQ4LCJjIjoxLCJkIjowLjZ9LCJtb2RlIjoiU01PT1RIIn0sInN5bW1ldHJ5IjpmYWxzZX0%3D). The goal is to store all data to replicate the artwork in the url while still being short enough to fit inside a tweet (280 chars in total).

#### Naive approach

The naive approach is simply to use `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse` and then encode the string as base64. It works, here is an example:

```
https://generativestudios.app/stained-glass?version=1&artwork=eyJzZWVkIjoiMjg5NjI1NDIiLCJzcGxpdHRpbmdTdHJhdGVneSI6IlNwbGl0IFJhbmRvbSBCYWxhbmNlZCIsImRlcHRoU3RyYXRlZ3kiOnsia2luZCI6IkluaGVyaXRlZCBEZXB0aCIsImRlcHRoIjo0fSwiZGlzdFN0cmF0ZWd5Ijp7ImtpbmQiOiJYIENlbnRyb2lkIn0sImppdHRlciI6MCwicGFsZXR0ZSI6eyJyZWQiOnsiYSI6MC40LCJiIjowLjU3OTAyMTk5Nzg4MjMxMTUsImMiOjAuNCwiZCI6MH0sImdyZWVuIjp7ImEiOjAuMiwiYiI6MC42MTE4ODc4NDg2MTc1MDUyLCJjIjowLjgsImQiOjB9LCJibHVlIjp7ImEiOjAuNiwiYiI6MC45MzA0MzA2NDU0OTUzOTQ4LCJjIjoxLCJkIjowLjZ9LCJtb2RlIjoiU01PT1RIIn0sInN5bW1ldHJ5IjpmYWxzZX0%3D
```

but unfortunately it is 560 characters long :(

#### Improved approach

Lets take a look the type of the data we are trying to encode:

```js
// What we want to encode in the URL
type Settings = {
  seed: string;
  splittingStrategy: SplittingStrategy;
  depthStrategy: DepthStrategy;
  distanceStrategy: DistanceStrategy;
  jitter: number;
  palette: Palette;
  symmetry: boolean;
};

// Helper types
type SplittingStrategy =
  | "Split Random"
  | "Split Random Balanced"
  | "Split Middle";

type DepthStrategy =
  | {
      kind: "Max Depth";
      maxDepth: number;
    }
  | {
      kind: "Flip Depth";
      maxDepth: number;
      p: number;
    }
  | {
      kind: "Inherited Depth";
      minDepth: number;
    };

type DistanceStrategy =
  | { kind: "XCentroid" }
  | { kind: "YCentroid" }
  | { kind: "DistanceToPoint"; x: number; y: number };

type Color = {
  a: Number;
  b: Number;
  c: Number;
  d: Number;
};

type Palette = {
  red: Color;
  green: Color;
  blue: Color;
  mode: "MOD" | "SMOOTH";
};
```

A couple of improvements springs to mind:

1. keys could be shortened to 1 character
2. the string enums could also be made 1 character long
3. Decimal numbers take a lot of space! Often we don't need all those decimals since 1 or 2 decimal places are good enough for our purpose.
4. Use cbor instead of json

Doing so shortens the encoding from **498** characters (not counting `http://...`) to **170** achiving our goal :)

```
# Naive
eyJzZWVkIjoiMjg5NjI1NDIiLCJzcGxpdHRpbmdTdHJhdGVneSI6IlNwbGl0IFJhbmRvbSBCYWxhbmNlZCIsImRlcHRoU3RyYXRlZ3kiOnsia2luZCI6IkluaGVyaXRlZCBEZXB0aCIsImRlcHRoIjo0fSwiZGlzdFN0cmF0ZWd5Ijp7ImtpbmQiOiJYIENlbnRyb2lkIn0sImppdHRlciI6MCwicGFsZXR0ZSI6eyJyZWQiOnsiYSI6MC40LCJiIjowLjU3OTAyMTk5Nzg4MjMxMTUsImMiOjAuNCwiZCI6MH0sImdyZWVuIjp7ImEiOjAuMiwiYiI6MC42MTE4ODc4NDg2MTc1MDUyLCJjIjowLjgsImQiOjB9LCJibHVlIjp7ImEiOjAuNiwiYiI6MC45MzA0MzA2NDU0OTUzOTQ4LCJjIjoxLCJkIjowLjZ9LCJtb2RlIjoiU01PT1RIIn0sInN5bW1ldHJ5IjpmYWxzZX0%3D

# Improved
p2EAomF2omEAYQBhAQNhaQJhAaJhdqFhAGEAYWkAYQL7QBwAAAAAAAFhA6RhAKRhAABhARgjYQIYZGEDGChhAaRhABRhARg%2BYQIYZGEDGFBhAmEBYQOkYQAYGWEBGD5hAhg8YQMYUGEEaDE2MTA1NjQ3YQVhAWEG9A%3D%3D
```

Of course, we might want to store more data in the URL at a later point...

What other tricks could one use? Is there another way to go about the problem? Is base64 the best binary-to-text encoding for our purpose?

Comment: This is quite a vague question to which there is no specifically correct answer. There are several libraries that make a stab at this ([for instance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-json)), but you might consider b64 encoded [protobuf](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/). I suspect that the more compressed, the more problematic it becomes when you decide to change the schema of the payload.

Comment: I'll probably have to try out a couple of approaches and see which ones fit my purpose the best. Who knows maybe I'll create a library of my own.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be possible to store compressed artwork in a URL, because there may be too much information to keep it to a tweet size or if you want to keep it under modern browser size limitations.

You could de-couple artwork from URL, for example, have a database table with `unique id <=> byte content`. The workflow will look like

```
HTTP GET https://generativestudios.app/stained-glass?artwork_id=eyJzZWVkIjoiMjg

# server makes a database call to look up artwork_id=eyJzZWVkIjoiMjg
# server returns the content of artwork to the user
```

If this is some sort of a code golf exercise and you must return artwork in URL, you could try the following:

- Shorted DNS name for the service
- Remove `stained-glass?version=1&`
- Compress artwork using slow and very dense compressor (e.g. LZMA, bzip2, LZHAM, brotli) then use URL safe encoding such as base58. Client side code then works in reverse to decode and decompress payload

Comment: Having a server would of course give the most optionality (at the cost of having a server but that could be okay). There is definitely an element of code golf to it haha. Though I don't need to store the entire artwork but only the parameters used to generate it (which is done on the client).